# How to Pass User Data into the SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I'm creating my own application.** Okay, let's see the code...

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'sqltest');
define('DB_USER', 'sqltest');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'sqltest');

$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
    or die ("failed to connect to db" . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn) 
    or die ("failed to connect to db" . mysql_error());


$v1 = @_POST['uname'];
$v2 = @_POST['pass'];
$v3 = @_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO userinfo (Username, Password, Email, userid) 
  VALUES ('$v1', '$v2', '$v3', 'NULL')";
$data = mysql_query($query);

if ($data === TRUE) {
    echo "Registration successfully";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Can you see the INSERT query? I passed some variables: **$v1, $v2, etc**.These variables are the variable for **$_POST**, to GET the user data and insert **that** data into the database.

The problem that I face here is when I inject data **(uname, pass, email, and *userid [automatic])** into my html form. The data didn't shown in the database but userid changes in the incremental form). I hope you understand point here.

I didn't succeed but I tried all the things I know. I really don't know what's wrong with it.

Can anyone please correct this and maybe provide an explanation too?

Thanks.

Comment: On an unrelated note to my answer, consider using `mysqli`. `mysql` has been deprecated for quite a while now, and was removed in PHP 7.0.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages while insertion?

Comment: No @Garbage Collector  i have use userid in the database. And that userid changes in incremental form. But in the data feild like uername, password, email injected data didn't come. Hope you got my point. if no see my question which i edited now.

Comment: `@_POST` is not a thing. You should get errors. `$_POST` is what you want.

Comment: Almost everything in this code is completely wrong, so if your goal is to create an optimially vunlerable code-base, that's the way to do it. Still, I get a rash from looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just typo :

```
$v1 = @_POST['uname'];

$v2 = @_POST['pass'];
$v3 = @_POST['email'];
```

change to :

```
$v1 = $_POST['uname'];

$v2 = $_POST['pass'];
$v3 = $_POST['email'];
```

"@" sign is used to hide error, like this :

```
$v1 = @$_POST['uname'];
```

Comment: Nice Catch! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your POST variables are missing $. Try:

```
$v1 = @$_POST['uname'];
$v2 = @$_POST['pass'];
$v3 = @$_POST['email'];
```

Btw, I don't recommend using @ to hide errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to avoid SQL injections.

The documentation is available [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: hello! Please read the full question. "I am creating my own application which is vulnerable to sql injection." I

Comment: Are you looking to create a SQL injection? I don't understand.

Comment: I think he is just trying to insert some data received through a `POST `request.

Comment: exactly garbage, @jhpratt emm, let's forgot about sql injection for a while. I am just trying to insert data

Comment: To get data from a POST request, you'll want to use `$_POST['name']`

Comment: Yeah!! but your answer is gonna help me in future because I am gonna secure my application with it. ;) thanks

Comment: That's a great idea :)